Oracle Managed Data Access Power Shell error
I need to use de .dll of Oracle Managed Data Access to connect to an Oracle 12 via script power shell but when I try to add the assembly path throws me this error:
Loader Exception: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have installed Net framework and the netstandard.dll is added to the path, the script is:
    $pathing = "C:\Users\javier.gomez\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.powershell-2024.2.1\modules\PowerShellEditorServices\bin\Desktop\netstandard.dll"

    Add-Type -Path $pathing

# Ruta hacia el archivo Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
    $assemblyPath = "C:\Users\javier.gomez\Desktop\ICGC-javi\Scripts-     Powershell\ScriptsISOPersonal\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"

    try {
        Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath
    } catch {
        if ($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions) {
            foreach ($ex in $_.Exception.LoaderExceptions) {
                Write-Host "Loader Exception: $($ex.Message)"
            }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Error al cargar la DLL: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}

# Define la cadena de conexión
$connectionString = "User Id=user;Password=pass;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=CRAVEN)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=GER1)))"

# Intenta crear una conexión Oracle con la cadena de conexión
try {
    $connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
    $connection.Open() # Abre la conexión
    Write-Host "Conexión Oracle establecida correctamente."
    $query = "SELECT * FROM GERENCIA.v_personal_unitats_sincro_ti"
     # Crea un comando Oracle con la consulta y la conexión
    $command = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($query, $connection)

     # Ejecuta la consulta y almacena el resultado en un lector de datos
    $reader = $command.ExecuteReader()

    # Itera sobre los resultados y muestra los datos
    while ($reader.Read()) {
        # Imprime el valor de la columna "email" si está presente
        if ($reader["nom"] -ne "") {
            Write-Host ("$($reader["nom"])")
        }
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Error al establecer la conexión Oracle: $_"
}

